# Flutter application block system clipboard on Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, clipboard

I'm a fairly newbie in Flutter, but ran into a super weird problem. Well, while I run the my code as "Desktop Windows" it blocks the **system** clipboard in windows. I mean, I can't copy anything to the clipboard IN THE WHOLE SYSTEM.

What is the problem and how to solve it? It's a bug or Flutter feature?

Frankly speaking, it's very annoying when during development I can't copy pieces of code or funny kittens to my friends on Discord.
The only way to stop it is to turn off the application.

How to repeat it:

- Run the application written in Flutter as "Desktop Windows" (it does not matter whether in the code editor or the previously built one)
- Run cmd / powershell and execute the command:

```
PS C:\Flutter\MySuperSimpleApp> echo "fubar" | clip
ERROR: Permission Denied
```

- Or try to copy and paste anything from/to any other windows application

P.S. My environment

```
System: Windows 11 Pro
Version: 21h2
Build: 22000.675

Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.671 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 32f61bc365 (7 days ago) • 5/12/2012 13:49:08 -0400
Engine • revision 35c770101a
Tools • Dart 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-106.0.dev) • DevTools 2.13.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a bug:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103205

Currently still not solved.